# Twitter API failed [403] usando full archive search con API Academica (rTweet)

Tags: r, scraping, twitter-api

Estoy tratando de recuperar algunos tweets históricos con rTweet y estoy recibiendo un error muy poco detallado cuando utilizo la función search_fullarchive y search_30 days. Esto NO ocurre cuando se buscan tweets no históricos. Tengo una API académica y estoy muy lejos del límite diario y mensual. Incluso con este ejemplo:

> rt <- search_fullarchive("#rstats", env_name = "Myenvironment",
> fromDate = "201401010000", toDate = "201401012359")

Obtengo este error>

> Error: Twitter API failed [403]
> Check error message at https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting

La página web no aclara cómo debo proceder. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar el paquete `academictwitteR`. Acá está la [documentación oficial](https://github.com/cjbarrie/academictwitteR). El asunto que ocurre con el paquete `rTweet`, es que no entrega los tweets históricos, ya que las actualizaciones en la API de Twitter, restringieron el acceso y sólo es posible a través del paquete `academictwitteR`. El paquete `rTweet`, te entrega una muestra de tweets de los ultimos 7-9 días contando desde el día de la llamada. En cambio con `academictwitteR` puede obtener la totalidad de tweets (siempre y cuando tengas la API académica).

Acá es un ejemplo de como acceder a lo tweets históricos siguiendo tu ejemplo:

```
tweets_data <- get_all_tweets(
  query = "#rstats",
  bearer_token = get_bearer(),
  has_image = FALSE,
  is_retweet = FALSE,
  file = "data",
  data_path = "./",
  start_tweets = "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  end_tweets = "2014-01-01T23:59:59Z",
  n = 10000
)
```

La variable get_bearer() la puedes reemplazar por la llave "AAAAA....". Pero si sigues los pasos de la instalación y documentación del paquete `academictwitteR` no debería haber problemas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Isaac, no tenía idea de la existencia del paquete. Ayer, después de algunos intentos fallidos pude hacer algo que vengo tratando de hacer hace casi un año. Para aquellos que no somos tan conocedores de la programación, no puedo terminar de explicarte cuánto me ha aportado tu respuesta. Que tengas una gran semana.